# How to know arithmetic mean of two count values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `answers` where I store information.

```
| EMPLOYEE | QUESTION_ID | QUESTION_TEXT          | SELECTED_OPTION_ID | SELECTED_OPTION_TEXT |
|----------|-------------|------------------------|--------------------|----------------------|
| Mark     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 1                  | Yes                  |
| Kate     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 1                  | Yes                  |
| Jone     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 2                  | No                   |
| Kim      | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 3                  | I don't know         |
| Alex     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 2                  | No                   |
| Bond     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 1                  | Yes                  |
| Ford     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 3                  | I don't know         |
| Mark     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 2                  | No                   |
| Kate     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 1                  | Yes                  |
| Jone     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 1                  | Yes                  |
| Kim      | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 1                  | Yes                  |
| Alex     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 2                  | No                   |
| Bond     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 1                  | Yes                  |
| Ford     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 3                  | I don't know         |
```

**Formulas**:

```
value_1 = (Number of users who answered "No" or "I don't know" to the first question) / (The total number of people who answered to the first question)

value_2 = (Number of users who answered "No" or "I don't know" to the second question) / (The total number of people who answered to the first question)
```

I can separately find the values according to the above formulas. For example `value_1`:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    answers
where
    question_id = 1
    and (
        selected_option_id in (2, 3)
        or 
        selected_option_text in ('No', 'I don\'t know')
    )
```

My question is how to arithmetic mean of these 2 values correctly by one sql query?

In other words I need to find average value:
[image]

Comment: What does the arithmetic mean signify in this context?

Comment: In other words, it's average value.

Comment: Generally arithmetic mean of two averages is quite nonsensical entity - unless both series sample count is known, then we can calculate weighted average. For example - if one serie consist of one sample and has average 0, other serie includes 1000 samples and has average 1, then we can't say that 1/2 is total average value. Fortunately OP formulas have always same sample counts - total number of people who answered to _first_ question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a condition sum

```
select  (sum( case when QUESTION_ID = 1 AND  
        SELECTED_OPTION_ID in ( 2,3) THEN 1 else 0 end )::float /  
      sum( case when QUESTION_ID = 1 then 1 else 0 end)::float )*100 first_question_rate,
    (sum( case when QUESTION_ID = 2 AND  
        SELECTED_OPTION_ID in ( 2,3) THEN 1 else 0 end )::float /  
      sum( case when QUESTION_ID = 2 then 1 else 0 end)::float)*100 second_question_rate,
    (( sum( case when QUESTION_ID = 1 AND  SELECTED_OPTION_ID in ( 2,3) THEN 1 else 0 end )::float /  
      sum( case when QUESTION_ID = 1 then 1 else 0 end)::float +
      sum( case when QUESTION_ID = 2 AND  SELECTED_OPTION_ID in ( 2,3) THEN 1 else 0 end )::float /  
      sum( case when QUESTION_ID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) ::float)/2)*100 avg 
from answer
```

Comment: I tested your script right now and it return zero in all the columns. It seems like a rounding of values happened. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: answer updated ..  adding   *100  .. but which data type are QUESTION_ID  and SELECTED_OPTION_ID  columns ?

Comment: which data type are  the columns QUESTION_ID and SELECTED_OPTION_ID  ???  are you sure these column contain integer and not string ?????

Comment: Type of both colomns is `int4`.

Comment: answer  updated .. casting float the number for avoid integer dvision

Comment: I notice that 3 colomn which we created (`first_question_rate`, `second_question_rate`, `avg `) has type `int8`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like below-

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE  WHEN QUESTION_ID = 1 AND SELECTED_OPTION_TEXT  <> 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
/
SUM(CASE  WHEN QUESTION_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) value_1 ,
SUM(CASE  WHEN QUESTION_ID = 2 AND SELECTED_OPTION_TEXT  <> 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
/
SUM(CASE  WHEN QUESTION_ID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) value_2
FROM answers
```

For getting average, please use the below script-

```
SELECT (A.value_1+A.value_2)/2.0 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    SUM(CASE  WHEN QUESTION_ID = 1 AND SELECTED_OPTION_TEXT  <> 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*1.0
    /
    SUM(CASE  WHEN QUESTION_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*1.0 value_1 ,
    SUM(CASE  WHEN QUESTION_ID = 2 AND SELECTED_OPTION_TEXT  <> 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*1.0
    /
    SUM(CASE  WHEN QUESTION_ID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*1.0 value_2
    FROM answers
)A
```

Comment: Hello! I tested your script right now and found strange behavior. Script return zero in all the columns. It seems like a rounding of values happened. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Can you please check the changed script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want conditional aggregation.  I suspect you want:

```
select question_id,
       count(*) filter (where selected_option_id in (2, 3)) as num_2_3,
       avg( selected_option_id in (2, 3)::int ) as ratio_2_3
from answers
group by question_id;
```

For each question, this provides the number of answers that are 2 or 3 and the ratio of those answers to all answers.

Comment: Can you check my post again please? I add additional information. I need to find average value.